# How to get the parent entry ID while inside relationship loop?

Tags: relationships, parent

I need to get the parent entry_id while I'm inside a relationship. This is what I have - doctors_locations is my relationship field name:

```
{doctors_locations}
    {doctors_locations:locations_city} {!-- outputs related city --}
    {doctors_locations:parents}{entry_id}{/doctors_locations:parents} {!-- I need the entry_id of the parent in this relationship --}
{/doctors_locations}
```

I've tried different iterations of this to no avail. Everything I've tried seems to cause a memory error -- assuming endless loop?

Is it possible to get the parent entry_id while inside of the relationship loop? I've managed to accomplish the same thing using Playa, but I needed to switch the doctors_locations field type to a Relationship field.

I'm using EE 2.10.1.

UPDATE: Based on the info here: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/relationships.html#accessing-parents I should be able to accomplish this. So I updated my code like this (tried it with just the title):

```
{doctors_locations}
    {doctors_locations:parents field="doctors_locations"}
        {doctors_locations:parents:title}
    {/doctors_locations:parents}
{/doctors_locations}
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal Error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1 bytes) in ../system/codeigniter/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_result.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're entering an infinite recursive loop with your code there, hence the memory exhaustion. All you need to do is this:

```
{doctors_locations}
    Location Title: {doctors_locations:title}
    Location Entry ID: {doctors_locations:entry_id}
    Doctor Title: {title}
    Doctor Entry ID: {entry_id}
{/doctors_locations}
```

You would only further use `{doctors_locations:parents}` if you wanted to fetch parents from a *different* channel/field than the parent channel you're already in via `channel:entries`.

Comment: I appreciate your prompt answer! I figured this out about 15 mins after I posted the original question. It was a "duh" moment!